# How to set the height of a wrapping div to prevent jumps in the content after a responsive slider/ticker?

Tags: jquery, css, height, responsive-design, ticker

I have made a super simple ticker/slider thingie with a few lines of code only, and it is somewhat responsive.

See [the code at jsBin](http://jsbin.com/ozozab/1/edit) and [the Demo](http://jsbin.com/ozozab/1) (Resize your screen and watch the ticker resize nicely.)

the basic HTML structure is:

```
<div id="tickerwrap">
    <ul id="ticker">
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        etc.
    </ul>
</div>
<div>Another div content</div>
```

And the jQuery is just:

```
function ticker () {
    $('#ticker li:first').slideUp (function () {
        $ (this).appendTo ($ ('#ticker')).slideDown ();
    });
}

setInterval (function (){ ticker (); }, 2500);
```

My problem is calculating the height of the wrapper div (`#tickerwrap`)...

1. How to prevent the "jump" when it is followed by another div?  See [this demo](http://jsbin.com/ozozab/2/edit).
2. How to calculate or set the height of the div when adding it to the DOM?

I have tried to add `ticker.stopPropagation();` and `ticker.preventDefault();` but it's no good.

I want the height/position to be responsive, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without making assumptions about the number or height of the ticker items (except we assume that there are more than 2), you pretty much need to use javascript to set the size of `#tickerwrap`.  To make it responsive to window resizes, use jQuery's `.resize()` with a  time-delay.

So, add this code ([See the demo](http://jsbin.com/exahaz/3)):

```
function sizeTickerwrap () {
    var tickerUL        = $('#ticker');
    var numTickerItems  = tickerUL.children ('li').length;
    if (numTickerItems  < 3)
        return;

    //-- The second item will not be in a slide animation.
    var itemHeight      = tickerUL.children ('li:eq(1)').outerHeight (true);
    //-- Adjust for the containing <ul>
    var wrapHeightAdjst = tickerUL.outerHeight (true) - tickerUL.height ();

    $("#tickerwrap").height (numTickerItems * itemHeight + wrapHeightAdjst);
}

//-- Initial call after a settling delay
setTimeout (sizeTickerwrap, 1200);

$(window).resize ( function () {
    /*-- Time-delay the resize response to give browser a chance to settle
        and avoid bogging down the UI.
    */
    this.resizeTimer    = this.resizeTimer || null;
    if (this.resizeTimer)
        clearTimeout (this.resizeTimer);

    this.resizeTimer    = setTimeout (sizeTickerwrap, 200);
} );
```

Comment: Thanks,  That looks .. great. and also much more complicated than whatI anticipated .. ( or my skills ) . Thanks . It actually the same idea of something I tried to do , But did not had the skills to complete : `jQuery("#tickerwrap").css( "height", jQuery("#k99-scroll-samurai first:li") *4);`

Comment: You're welcome.  Note that I had a small typo in the code (was `+`; should be `-`; see [the edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/16504635/revisions#revf3600d3b-3599-4751-b2b1-15304b903b32)).

Comment: Hi, I took the time to study your sctipt ( just in the phase of learning better js , and trying to study .. ) and I noticed that your script assumes that all the `li` elements will be the same height ( by measuring the second `li(eq:1)` and multiplying) . I just want to know the reason why you did not just take the height of ALL the elements together ? is that because they are changing ? is there a way to measure the elements 'BEFORE' the slide action starts ? becasue otherwise the script is miscalculating when the elements are of different heights.( http://jsbin.com/exahaz/11/edit )

Comment: You can measure the height *one time* before the slide action starts.  But measuring the height on resizes, after that, gets noticeably trickier.  Probably best to open a new question for this requirement.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot for your help, I learned a lot from your code :-)